# Is there a way to use Injectable Service in ngModule to initialize firebase app in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using firebase in my application. The firebase configuration was stored in environment file.

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebase: {
     apiKey: "api-key",
     authDomain: "project-id.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://project-id.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "project-id",
     storageBucket: "project-id.appspot.com",
     messagingSenderId: "sender-id",
     appID: "app-id",
  }
};
```

And I initialized the firebase App using that config.

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [],
})
export class InboxModule {}
```

So far, so good. But I wanted to fetch firebase configuration from API call depending on the brand, and initialize the app based on the response.

I wrote an Injectable Service, for storing the configuration.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  private _firebaseConfig = null;

  constructor() {}

  get firebaseConfig() {
    return this._firebaseConfig;
  }

  set firebaseConfig(val) {
    this._firebaseConfig = val;
  }
}
```

But I'm unable to use it in ngModule.

```
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { FirebaseService } from '../services/firebase.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [],
})
export class InboxModule {
  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(this.firebaseService.firebaseConfig);
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error.

```
Error: No provider for InjectionToken FirebaseAppConfigToken!
```

which is due to not initializing the app properly.

```
export class InboxModule {
  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) {
   console.log(this.firebaseService.firebaseConfig) // Works
   // Unable to initialize the App though.
   AngularFireModule.initializeApp(this.firebaseService.firebaseConfig);
  }
}
```

Any thing I'm missing? or any other way to solve this use case?